# Server.MapPath gives error with UNC

Tags: c#, unc, server.mappath, mappath

Here is my directory to my server (permissions are good):

```
string ServerPath = ("\\\\servername\\Public\\Intranet2007Docs");
```

Here I am accessing it:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(ServerPath));
```

And here is the error:

[image]

Any help would be great. I don't understand why it won't map the path to the UNC.

Comment: @, ~, //, and . are all for directories on local machine and they do not work to access a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not using the server.MapPath:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("\\\\servername\\Public\\Intranet2007Docs");
```

Comment: This was the issue...it didn't like the mappath! Using the unc directly inside worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `MapPath` on a path that is inside the web application. Any path outside the web application doesn't have a corresponding URL.

Besides, the `DirectoyInfo` method doesn't have any use for an URL, so you should simply not use `MapPath` at all:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(ServerPath);
```